# Integrating WordPress into Kohana vs Kohana into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, kohana

I'm starting work on a personal site that's primarily a blog, with a section for various tech projects as small as a custom photo gallery to as large as a restaurant-review web-app. Not having worked with WordPress or Kohana before, I'm curious what the advantages are of integrating WP into Kohana (or any other framework, for that matter), and vice versa, given this situation.

I've seen bits of this mentioned here and there online, but no definite post comparing the two approaches, so I'm hoping others can pitch in here :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this before, but kerkness has written a plugin for it: https://github.com/kerkness/kohana-for-wordpress However, it is quite old so you might want to look for something newer.

Comment: Hey Pixel, I know about that particular plugin, but I'm curious more about the theoretical/practical differences between the two approaches of WP-Kohana integration

Comment: Hi,can you please check my so question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934551/access-data-from-kohana-to-wordpress which is for integrating kohana with wordpress.

Comment: @Johnny Hi,can you please check my so question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934551/access-data-from-kohana-to-wordpress which is for integrating kohana with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Wordpress with a framework (be it Kohana, CodeIgniter, Zend, etc.) is often sought without addressing the first and most important question: **How far do you want to integrate the two at a feature level?**

Broadly speaking, there are two high-level approaches to integrating any two PHP products:

**1)** In the PHP code, include the libraries, bootstrap scripts, etc. from both products into a script or scripts (creating a "hybrid").

As a developer you should be able to use *most* of the features from both products in the resulting hybrid. For example, in the case of Wordpress and Kohana, the complete result would allow you to use Kohana features (e.g., routing, auth, etc.) and Wordpress features (e.g., fetching post contents, authors, etc.).

The difficulty with this approach is competing APIs and code expectations that might make the hybrid behave unexpectedly, e.g.,

- Will there be competition between the class autoloaders?
- Are there duplicate function or class definitions?
- How extensively can plugins in Wordpress be supported if they depend on PHP settings that the framework is going to change on bootstrap?

The first issue I would want to resolve when attempting this process is the routing, am I going to delegate fetching of posts, attachments, etc. to Wordpress from within Kohana, or am I going to have to build an interface between Kohana's router, controllers and Wordpress?

While this option is appealing because you can access both product APIs, you must be prepared to make significant changes to the application behaviour in order to allow both products to co-exist peacefully. If this sounds like a lot of work, it is because it is a lot of work!

**2)** Use the webserver to intelligently route requests to different products.

From your question, it sounds like you want parts of the website to load web applications that don't necessarily need the level of integration indicated above (e.g., would you really need to get Wordpress API in the review application, or the photo gallery?). If you are just looking for a way to load two applications using the same application domain, this option would be better suited because you don't need to perform much (if any) integration between the two.

Assuming you are using a webserver like nginx or Apache Httpd, you should be able to create aliases for different parts of the site to different applications.

e.g.,

http://myblog.nonex/ - points to the Wordpress installation, which in turn manages the default site (shows pages, blog posts, etc. all from Wordpress).

http://myblog.nonex/apps/review - points to the review application, which is the Kohana installation.

http://myblog.nonex/apps/gallery - points to the gallery application, which (with proper modularisation) could exist alongside the review application in the same Kohana installation.

Since you are still in the planning and development stage, I would recommend going for option 2) first - build a prototype, identify any areas where you absolutely need features from Wordpress in Kohana (e.g., would either the review or gallery application need to use the Wordpress user credentials?) and look at performing a minimal integration before creating a full hybrid.

Comment: can you please check my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934551/access-data-from-kohana-to-wordpress which is related to integration of kohana and wordpress